# Removing white space at the start of a beautifulsoup element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the most important part of the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

all = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"general-content"})

for item in all:
    print(item.find("span", {"class":"posting-location go-to-posting"}).text)
    try:
        print(item.find("span", {"class":"first-price"}).text)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        print(item.find("span", {"class":"expenses"}).text)
    except:
        pass
    print(item.find("ul", {"class":"main-features go-to-posting"}).text)
    print(item.find("ul", {"class":"posting-features go-to-posting"}).text)
```

It returns the data I want but the problem is that it does it with a large amount of white spaces at the beginning. At first I thought it was a string so I used .lstrip() and .strip() and it had this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
```

If I check the type of "all" it returns this: `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`. Everything I could find about replacing white spaces is only for strings. Does someone know what can I do about this?

Comment: You need to apply lstrip on text. ```.text.lstrip()```. Your error will occur if ```item.find()``` returns None

Comment: @broadwaydannyrose  share your website link.